# New Relic plugin doesn't create alert when service is down

Tags: newrelic-platform

I'm monitoring few services with New Relic plugins (memcached, mongodb, etc). They show me statistics from this services, but when service is down, there is no alerts from New Relic. Only zeros in services statistics. How to configure plugins to create alerts? 
I'm using latest version of newrelic-plugin-agent https://github.com/MeetMe/newrelic-plugin-agent.

Answer (score 1):

We are aware that low water mark thresholds are something our users want and that feature is on our road map to develop. In the interim, plugin authors are able to work around the issue. If you reach out to the MeetMe author, an intermediate solution could be written into the plugin for this specific use case.

Cheers,

Serene C.

New Relic Platform engineer

Comment: Any word on this? I can't seem to figure out how to raise an alert when a service is down...